# How to manipulate array

Tags: java, for-loop

How to manipulate the for loop, the question is on the comments
How to re-enter the for loop and adding the index dynamically except for the auto increment.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
{             
try {
     temp = QueryWithContext.query(words.get(i));
     if((temp == null || temp.isEmpty()) && words.size() > i+1)
      {
        QueryWithContext.query(words.get(i)+" "+words.get(i+1));
        temp = QueryWithContext.query(words.get(i)+" "+words.get(i+1));
        System.out.println("1st if");
        //if condition = true, the codes below must not run anymore 
        //and for loop will increment by 1 except for the auto inc
        if((temp == null || temp.isEmpty()) && words.size() > i+2)
         {
            System.out.println("2nd if");
            temp = QueryWithContext.query(words.get(i)+" "+                                                                    
                                     words.get(i+1)+" "+words.get(i+2));
            //if condition = for loop will increment by 2 
            //except for the auto inc
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: To change how the loop variable increments, just increment the variable manually, i.e. i+=2 for instance. Also, you may want to read up on break and continue.

Comment: The question isnt very clear? What do you mean by "manipulate the for loop" and by "adding the index dynamically except for the auto increment"?

Comment: The question is terrible bad formatted. Please ask the question on the "question" not on the code!

Comment: what do you mean by "for loop will increment by 2 except for the auto inc"?

Answer (score 1):

If you meant increasing the loop index, then you can increase the `i` value that represents the index. `i += 2;` should do the work. It will eventually increase it by 3 when the loop ends and starts over.